# Datagrid Grouping displaying the Field value that you are grouping on as Header

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am trying to Group Items in a DataGrid and display the value of the Field it is grouping on in the header.  For example:

Ford - 3 items
  F150
  Mustang
Chevy - 2 items

Every example I have looked at shows me the exact same thing which doesn't seem to work at all for me.

```
<DataGrid IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectionUnit="FullRow"  RowHeaderWidth="0"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding View}"  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedContingency, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"   >
           <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.Panel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.Panel>
                        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <Expander>
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <TextBlock Text=" wtf " />
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"/> 
                                                    <TextBlock Text=" Items" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

Also had this for a while but it made no difference

```
<GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
```

Instead of getting a description here I just get ( wtf 3 items ) etc.  I've tried different fields and nothing.  I've tried every variation I can think of for the field in the exapander header.

What magic is required to make this common feature function?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is that in the examples they bind to the field name.  So when you see in the examples:

```
<Expander.Header>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"> 
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name"} /> 
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"/> 
                                                <TextBlock Text=" Items" />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Expander.Header>
```

You might assume as I did that "Name" is used because thats also the field they chose to bind to.  This is not the case.  "Name" is the actual property on the GroupItem that you are binding to that has the value.

So no matter what Field you are grouping on, you always display that field by binding to "Name" on the GroupItem.